# Is Zp∞ a torsion group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is Zp∞ a torsion group?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D99Vu.jpg)

Comment: About Zp∞ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group

Comment: Who upvoted this question?  It clearly doesn't fit the rules of how to ask questions here.

Comment: @Xam I don't think there is a rule that says that one must always vote according to the rules. Maybe the person was just interested in the subject the question handled.

Comment: @guojm please don't use links to images off the site, try and keep as much as possible related to the question contained in the question body and as much mathematic formula as possible in MathJax / LaTeX typesetting format. Doing so will greatly increase your chances of positive responses on the site. Ignoring to do so may cause your questions to be closed & unanswerable.

Comment: @mathreadler sure there isn't a rule, but IMO upvoting this kind of questions may suggest to the OP that is acceptable to ask in this way.

Comment: @Xam I think the comments as well as the other votes generally send a quite clear signal that something is wrong, but to a new user it would probably be more helpful with a guiding message than downvotes IMO.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for your kindness.I have learned LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ is the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group). This is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, and hence torsion. We may identify  $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as the torsion subgroup of the circle group $S^1\simeq
\{\text{$z\in\Bbb C$ such that $||z||=1 $}\}$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. What is S1?

Comment: $S^1 \neq \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Redirecting PseudoNeo's comment...

Comment: @AlexVong See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391327/mathbbq-mathbbz-has-cyclic-subgroup-of-every-positive-integer-n), Andrea Mori's answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, you mean the unit circle in the complex plane under multiplication.